# Iron Router: Escape a '?' in an incoming Twilio message

Tags: meteor, twilio, iron-router

This is probably straightforward, but I couldn't find any direct answers:

I am writing a bot that answers questions asked through SMS. Twilio routes the questions to a webhook, and I extract the body of the message and the sender's phone number to prepare the reply. This works well when the SMS body doesn't include `?` (as most questions do). When it does, the request is truncated after the `?` and I can't read the number field.

Example:

```
Router.route('/twilio/', function() {
  console.log('%j', this.params.query);
  var number = this.params.query.From;
  var body = this.params.query.Body;
  var args = {
    number: number,
    message: body
  }
  this.response.end(Meteor.call('sendMessage', args));
}, {
  where: 'server'
});
```

Here is the log when the question is asked with a `?` (e.g. "How are you doing today?")

```
{"ToCountry":"US","ToState":"MI","SmsMessageSid":"SM7bb1aee8c38c567e916c715672b5a201","NumMedia":"0","ToCity":"OXFORD","FromZip":"07950","SmsSid":"SM7bb1aee8c38c567e916c715672b5a201","FromState":"NJ","SmsStatus":"received","FromCity":"CALDWELL","Body":"How are you doing today"}
```

Here is it without the `?` (e.g. "How are you doing today")

```
{"ToCountry":"US","ToState":"MI","SmsMessageSid":"SM00d6a0c1bfec40c2372ed2cc255af918","NumMedia":"0","ToCity":"OXFORD","FromZip":"07950","SmsSid":"SM00d6a0c1bfec40c2372ed2cc255af918","FromState":"NJ","SmsStatus":"received","FromCity":"CALDWELL","Body":"How are you doing today","FromCountry":"US","To":"+1xxxxxxxxxx","ToZip":"48367","NumSegments":"1","MessageSid":"SM00d6a0c1bfec40c2372ed2cc255af918","AccountSid":"ACc8f77bee1430f42600b6f83d7174384c","From":"+1234567890","ApiVersion":"2010-04-01"}
```

I couldn't find any way to have Twilio encode the GET request. Barring that is there a way for Iron Router to escape special characters within the message body?
If not, is the only solution converting to POST request?

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like a bug if Iron Router cuts off responses like that. I'm not sure if I have the time to look into this right now, but will have a dig around.